# Remove SNAPSHOT suffix from Jenkins build

Tags: maven, jenkins

I recently upgraded from hudson to jenkins. Since they are practically the same I thought it would be just plug and play. I noticed that when I build my projects my war files are being appended with the SNAPSHOT version instead of just .war. I didn't have this problem in hudson.

Is there a way to globally tell jenkins to use the release war, the one in my target directory, as it's artifact build file or have jenkins, I'm assuming the maven plugin, to not append the SNAPSHOT to the file?

Answer (score -1):

`SNAPSHOT` is added on purpose. Don't mess with it. Either use bleeding-edge or perform `mvn release:prepare release:perform` in batch mode from Jenkins.